# MemoryStream download fails from IIS6 to IIS7

Tags: iis-7, iis-6, download, memorystream

We are converting from IIS6 to IIS7 and all has went very well except our download section. What happens is the download is initiated, but it appears a redirect is taking place and our default.aspx page is downloaded instead of the requested file by the user. Below is the code we used with IIS6.

```
Private Sub GetFile(ByVal ReportQueueId As System.Int32, _
                    ByVal FileName As System.String _
                    )
    Dim stream As System.IO.MemoryStream = Nothing
    Dim lngRecordCount As System.Int32 = 0
    Dim objWebClient As New System.Net.WebClient
    Dim strServerName As System.String

    Try
        strServerName = Page.Request.Item("SERVER_NAME").ToString()

        Dim fURI As New System.Uri("http://" & strServerName & "/reportmonitor/" & FileName)
        ' Open the file into a stream. 
        stream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(objWebClient.DownloadData(fURI), False)

        ' Total bytes to read: 
        Dim bytesToRead As Long = stream.Length

        Page.Response.Clear()
        Page.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
        Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & FileName.ToString())
        Page.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytesToRead.ToString())


        ' Read the bytes from the stream in small portions. 
        While bytesToRead > 0
            ' Make sure the client is still connected. 
            If Response.IsClientConnected Then
                ' Read the data into the buffer and write into the output stream. 
                Dim buffer As Byte() = New Byte(9999) {}
                Dim length As Integer = stream.Read(buffer, 0, 10000)
                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length)
                Response.Flush()

                ' We have already read some bytes.. need to read 
                ' only the remaining. 
                bytesToRead = bytesToRead - length
            Else
                ' Get out of the loop, if user is not connected anymore.. 
                bytesToRead = -1
            End If
        End While

        'Update status
        lngRecordCount = UpdateStatus(ReportQueueId, _
                                      listcounts_common.ListCountsCommon_CL.ReportQueueStatus.rqsDownloaded _
                                      )
    Catch SystemException As System.Exception
        'Update status
        lngRecordCount = UpdateStatus(ReportQueueId, _
                                      listcounts_common.ListCountsCommon_CL.ReportQueueStatus.rqsOnHold _
                                      )

        'most likely a 404 file not found error
        Me.lblErrorMessage.Text = CLASS_NAME & ":GetFile: " & SystemException.Message.ToString
        Me.lblErrorMessage.Visible = True
    Finally
        objWebClient = Nothing
        stream = Nothing
    End Try
End Sub
```

After this code is run the only other thing I have read it might be is in the parent function that calls GetFile() we have code for the following:

```
' stops page html output. If this is not done, un-desired html code will be added to csv files
 Page.Response.End()
```

Any thoughts on the difference between IIS6 and 7 and this process? Everything I have tried has not worked. The new site is running in Itegrated Mode, .NET 4.

Thank you...

**UPDATE**

I modified the fURI to be an external file:

```
fURI = New System.Uri("http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/ipad_user_guide.pdf")
```

This file downloads perfectly, so I am assuming it is a permissions issue in IIS7...any ideas on what I may have missed?

Answer (score 0):

Since the site is using Forms Authentication, adding an allowable location path in the web.config for the virtual resolved the issues in converting to IIS7.

```
<location path="reportmonitor">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```